# 19.10: Enable encryption in ZFS

Tags: encryption, zfs

When you choose the experimental ZFS on Linux option in the Ubuntu installation of 19.10 (and also 20.04), you end up with something like this:

```
NAME                                               USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
bpool                                             91,8M  1,66G       96K  /boot
bpool/BOOT                                        91,1M  1,66G       96K  none
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_uxtu99                          91,0M  1,66G     91,0M  /boot
rpool                                             4,93G   886G       96K  /
rpool/ROOT                                        4,22G   886G       96K  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uxtu99                          4,22G   886G     3,60G  /
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uxtu99/srv                        96K   886G       96K  /srv
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uxtu99/usr                       224K   886G       96K  /usr
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uxtu99/usr/local                 128K   886G      128K  /usr/local
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uxtu99/var                       487M   886G       96K  /var
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uxtu99/var/games                  96K   886G       96K  /var/games
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uxtu99/var/lib                   479M   886G      373M  /var/lib
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uxtu99/var/lib/AccountServices    96K   886G       96K  /var/lib/AccountServices
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uxtu99/var/lib/NetworkManager    160K   886G      160K  /var/lib/NetworkManager
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uxtu99/var/lib/apt              62,6M   886G     62,6M  /var/lib/apt
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uxtu99/var/lib/dpkg             43,5M   886G     43,5M  /var/lib/dpkg
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uxtu99/var/log                  7,06M   886G     7,06M  /var/log
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uxtu99/var/mail                   96K   886G       96K  /var/mail
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uxtu99/var/snap                   96K   886G       96K  /var/snap
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uxtu99/var/spool                 124K   886G      124K  /var/spool
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uxtu99/var/www                    96K   886G       96K  /var/www
rpool/USERDATA                                     715M   886G       96K  /
rpool/USERDATA/blah_mk6ljb                          714M   886G      711M  /home/blah
rpool/USERDATA/root_mk6ljb                         640K   886G      640K  /root`
```

I was able to enable `dedup` and `compression` but not `encryption`.
`zfs get compression` shows `lz4` and `on` for `dedup` (except on boot pool).
The command `sudo zpool set feature@encryption=enabled rpool` doesn't cause any errors but `zfs get encryption` afterwards still shows encryption `off`.

How do I enabled encryption and choose a cipher etc..?

Why all of these pools? `www`, `snap`, `mail`, `games`... Can I get rid of them?

This is on a 1TB SSD, in case that is relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question: How do I enabled encryption and choose a cipher etc..?

ZFS encryption can only be enabled at the time of pool or filesystem creation. The cipher is set as an option. Easiest way is performing the following steps when installing Ubuntu.

- Boot from install ISO.
- Click the **Try Ubuntu** option.
- Open the terminal application.
- Sudo to root. No password required.
- Edit **/usr/share/ubiquity/zsys-setup**.
- Search for **zpool create** command applicable to the **rpool**.
- Preprend `echo MYPASSWORD |` to the zpool command.
- Add the following lines before the last zpool create option line.

```
-O encryption=aes-256-gcm \
-O keylocation=prompt \
-O keyformat=passphrase \
```

Please ensure to use double quotes around the password escaping bash characters "\$ if used in the password.

The result should look like the following

```
echo <password> | zpool create -f \
        ...
        -O encryption=aes-256-gcm \
        -O keylocation=prompt \
        -O keyformat=passphrase \
        -O mountpoint=/ -R "${target}" rpool "${partrpool}"
```

- Run **ubiquity** to start the installer

> Question2: Why all of these pools? www, snap, mail, games... Can I get rid of them?

Those www, snap, mail entries are ZFS file systems mounted at the mentioned mount points, not ZFS pools. These filesystems are where files are stored and there is no issue in having lots of ZFS file systems. In fact that is one of the advantages of ZFS in offering great flexibility with file system layouts, snapshots, naming and performance tuning.

You can delete them, but that means it will delete all files located within that file system.

Comment: To be clear, you can enable encryption on a dataset when creating it (`zfs create`), you do not have to enable it when creating the pool (`zpool create`). See for example https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/06/a-quick-start-guide-to-openzfs-native-encryption/

Comment: ZFS encryption can only be enabled at the time of pool or filesystem creation. This means encryption must be defined at time of creation whether you are creating a pool or a filesystem. The question is about adding encryption post creation to a Ubuntu install where the pool becomes a requirement. A general creating a zfs encrypted file system on an preexisting pool is not relevant in this context.